# How to properly verify SSL cert? (Having a problem)

Tags: openssl

I completed the following steps to generate my SSL cert request:

```
openssl genrsa -out key 2048
openssl req -new -key key -out csr
```

Then I submitted my csr to my signing authority, and got my cert back.

I put in in a file named  "cert"

Now I want to verify that the cert is correct.

```
openssl verify cert
```

I get the original O and OU results back, but additionally I get the following error:

```
error 20 at 0 depth lookup:unable to get local issuer certificate
```

Am I correctly verifying the cert, and if so, why am I getting this error? If not, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Openssl is trying to check the issuer certificate in order to verify your certificate you need to extend your command as follows:-

openssl verify [-CAfile cafile] file

where file is the cert you previously specified and cafile is the cafile of the root CA.

Mark Sutton 
http://www.blacktipconsulting.com

Answer (score 3):

Is the CA cert of the issuer present on your system ? You have to check that the issuer's certificate chain is installed in order to validate in-depth your certificate. On most linuxes, public certificate are stored under /etc/ssl.